# InsertionSort what is wrong with the loop guards

Tags: python

Why isn't the 9 getting sorted? I've played around with my loop conditions but can't see the error:

```
def insertionSort(L):
    n = len(L)
    for x in range(1,n):
        tgtNum = L[x]
        for y in range(x-1,-1,-1):
            if L[y] > tgtNum:
                L[y], L[x] = L[x], L[y]
            print(L)
        print()
    return(L)

myList = [2,9,1,7,5]
print(insertionSort(myList))
```

Comment: shouldn't the range be from 0 to n?

Comment: actually ur doing little wrong. in insertion sort we need to find least number in the array and replace them with first.Right?

Comment: @sundarnatarajサンダーナタラジ insertion sort should have a sorted partition, in this case on the left. It loops from L to R in the unsorted partition - for each item it then looks back to the sorted partition and loops though that R to L looking for the point where it should be inserted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution, your second for loop was your problem

```
def insertionSort(L):
    n = len(L)
    for x in range(1,n):
        tgtNum = L[x]
        for y in range(0, x):
            if L[y] > tgtNum:
                temp = L[y]
                L[y] = L[x]
                L[x] = temp
            print(L)
        print()
    return(L)

myList = [2,9,1,7,5]
print(insertionSort(myList))
```

The output is: `[1,2,5,7,9]`

Comment: +1 thanks Dylan. Why the use of temp - don't you trust the short version? I think its great notation `L[y], L[x] = L[x], L[y]`

Comment: Yeah that is better notation, I guess using `temp` as part of my swap routine is just old habits :-)

Comment: The statement `tgtNum = L[x]` is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah I know, I just kept it in because that was in the original code posted above.